# Hide A Table Header If Cell Value Is Null

Tags: c#, html

I have a `<table>` which has 4 columns but I want the first column to be hidden if the cell value is `null`

I have managed to hide each row in the table but I cant get my head around how to apply this to my table headers.

This is all done in my HTML as show below

```
<%
var app = (AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.Client.Application.Sippcentre)AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Wrappers.Session.Process.Data;
%>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
<%--        <% if (app.IsChild)
            { %>--%>
            <th>CTF unique ref number</th>
<%--        <%} %>--%>
        <th>Provider</th>
        <th>Account number</th>
        <th>Approximate value</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        Int32 i = 0;
            foreach (AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.Client.Application.Products.IsaTransfer t in Model.Products.IsaDetails.IsaTransfers)
            {
                i++; %>
                <tr>
                    <% if (app.IsChild && t.UniqueCTFRef !=null)
                            { %>
                            <td><%: AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.Functions.Truncate(t.UniqueCTFRef,25) %></td>
                        <%} %>
                    <td><%: AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.Functions.Truncate(t.Manager,25) %></td>
                    <td><%: AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.Functions.Truncate(t.AccountNumber,25) %></td>
                    <td><%: String.Format("{0:C}",t.ApproximateValue) %></td>
                </tr>
            <%} %>
</table>
```

The commented out bit is the column header I want to hide.  It will have 2 conditions, one if the app is a child and the other if the cell value is not `null`.

An example of this can be seen in the code above and below (this is the same code)

```
<%
    Int32 i = 0;
        foreach (AJBG.Web.Services.Entities.Client.Application.Products.IsaTransfer t in Model.Products.IsaDetails.IsaTransfers)
        {
            i++; %>
            <tr>
                <% if (app.IsChild && t.UniqueCTFRef !=null)
                        { %>
                        <td><%: AJBG.CMS2.Sippcentre.AppCode.Functions.Functions.Truncate(t.UniqueCTFRef,25) %></td>
                    <%} %>
```

I cant move my `foreach` otherwise I end up with a header row for every entry in the table.

It will probably be something simple, just I cant figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about change your condition for your header from:

```
if (app.IsChild)
```

into this

```
if (app.IsChild && Model.Products.IsaDetails.IsaTransfers.Any(t => t.UniqueCTFRef == null))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it complains about 'Any' as it doesn't contain a definition for 'Any' and there's also no extension method for it

Comment: Add the "@using System.Linq" to the top of your view.

Comment: I have tried adding <%@ Import namespace="System.Linq" %> but still doesn't recognise the 'Any'

Comment: it has acutally worked evn though the code is underlined red.  It also worked without needing to the add the System.Linq.  Did a rebuild and it never complained so must be ok. Thanks